# Use OR and AND in MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to use the OR and AND selector together in a MySQL query, but the last AND has no effect on the result. This is my current SQL query:

```
$sql->setQuery("SELECT * FROM rex_projekte 
                                WHERE projektname LIKE '%$suche%' 
                                    OR projektnummer_hw LIKE '%$suche%' 
                                    OR projektnummer_k LIKE '%$suche%' 
                                AND gruppe = 'new'");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

```
$sql->setQuery("SELECT * FROM rex_projekte 
                                WHERE (projektname LIKE '%$suche%' 
                                    OR projektnummer_hw LIKE '%$suche%' 
                                    OR projektnummer_k LIKE '%$suche%') 
                                AND gruppe = 'new'");
```

Comment: Welcome :) @susanloek

Answer (score 2):

Juste use brackets

```
SELECT * 

FROM rex_projekte 

WHERE 

( projektname LIKE '%$suche%' OR projektnummer_hw LIKE '%$suche%' OR projektnummer_k LIKE '%$suche%' )

AND gruppe = 'new'
```

Comment: Thank you, ThinkTank! Works fine!